# Magento: export products to csv or excel

Tags: excel, magento, csv, magento-1.4

I want to export the complete list of products in our Magento website, to CSV or Excel. How can I do this? Is this standard functionality? In the admin I couldn't find anything, not in the products page, not in reports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in **`System`**->**`Import/Export`**->**`Dataflow – Profiles`**->**`Export All Products`**.

Setting up a profile allows you to specify attributes for the export as explained [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles)